# Remove duplicate in sorted array, try to understand

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicate value from a sorted array.
Here's my code.

```
public static int remove (int[] nums, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){     
            //tried to print out here 
            if(nums[i] == nums[i-1]) count++;
            else nums[i-count] = nums[i];
        }
        return n-count;
    }
```

My array is `{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5}`.

I tried to print out the value of the variable so I can understand how it works. In the first loop iteration, before the IF condition `if i = 1`, why is that the value of `numb[i]` is already 2?

Thanks

Comment: A simple google search of "Javascript loops" would have given you your answer. Always do the basic research before posting a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because arrays are zero-based in Java (and many other languages). The indices of an array of size *n* would be `{ 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 }` so, to start at the first element of an array would be `array[0]`.

But you don't want to do that here of course because you're checking each element with the one before it. If `i` started at `0` in your loop you'd get an exception.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I'm still learning and got confused sometimes.